# indirect reference to a structure variable using a string variable in Matlab

Tags: matlab, variables, call

I'm trying to create a variable where I can type in a string corresponding to a variable in a structure, so that I can create a set of plots when the only difference between the plots is the variable.

I.e.  Currently:

```
example(1:100).variable1=[matrix]
example(1:100).variable2=[matrix]
example(1:100).variable3=[matrix]
for i=1:100
   figure (i)    
   surf(x,y,example(i).variable1)    
   [Formatting code]

   surf(x,y,example(i).variable2)
   [Formatting code]

   surf(x,y,example(i).variable3)    
   [Formatting code]
end
```

Since there is a fair bit of formatting code and I only care about one variable at a time, I'd like a better way than commenting out whichever set I want/don't want.

Is there a way to do the following?

I.e. Ideal:

```
example(1:100).variable1=[matrix]
example(1:100).variable2=[matrix]
example(1:100).variable3=[matrix]

stringVariable='variable1'

for i=1:100
   surf(x,y,example(i).stringVariable)    
   [Formatting code]
end
```

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this in matlab is to encapsulate the variable in parentheses when using it to reference a struct field.

For example:

```
>> thisstruct.A = [1 1 1];
>> thisstruct.B = [0 0 0];
>> variable = 'A';
>> thisstruct.(variable)
ans =
 1     1     1
>> variable = 'B';
>> thisstruct.(variable)
ans =
     0     0     0
```

Comment: I completely forgot I even asked a question here, but thanks for the answer! Never figured it out even after a year and a half!